# Manage multiple redirection rules on HTML site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am moving a website from Wordpress (server 1) to HTML (server 2) and I have a lot of 301 Redirection rules that I need to implement.

I know that I can add these 301 Redirection rules in .htaccess but they are lots of them, 100s of rules.

**What's the best / efficient way for me to add the 301 Redirection rules on the new HTML (server 2)?**

PS: from my understanding, the bigger the .htaccess the longer it takes to be processed; that's why I don't want to have a htaccess file with 1000+ lines :(

Thank you!

Comment: Certainly placing such rules in the central server configuration is more efficient, since the rules do not have to be re-read for each and every request. But for that you need administrative access to that central configuration. You have that if you operate that http server yourself, you do _not_ have that if you are using a shared hosting.

Comment: Another approach would be to have just a single redirection rule that redirects _all_ requests to some central routing script you have. That might be implemented in the new server. This would allow to use a database for example to lookup rules, you can implement your own redirection logic. Much flexibility, but of course you need some form of scripting to implement such a logic.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the `RedirectMap` directive available within the apache rewriting module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Comment: Oh, and you need to sort out what server will actually first respond to your requests. If you implement that new static site on a different http server then you probably want to adjust the DNS resolution of your domain as well.

Comment: @arkascha I have access to the server, it's my server, but I have other domains there as well. my server is on Virtualmin/Webmin and OS is RHEL based; any idea whereabouts I'd set this up? thank you!

Comment: @arkascha "Another approach would be to have just a single redirection rule .."

Yes this would be great, yeah.

"You might also want to take a look at the RedirectMap"
cool thank you, looks interesting

"If you implement that new static site on a different http server then you probably want to adjust the DNS resolution of your domain as well."
Yes, it will be on a new different server, I will change the DNS as well but my main issue is managing all the redirections.

I will test first on a staging domain to see how it works, separate domain.

Comment: You don't actually need another domain for testing the rules. You can do that locally. Just create a static name resolution for your domain inside your local development system, that's all you need.

Comment: And just to make sure you understood what I mentioned in my first comment: you do understand the difference between the central server configuration of an apache http server and a ".htaccess" style file? If not check the documentation. Oh, and you want to make sure that your new server actually is an apache http server and not some other http server software.

Comment: @arkascha to be honest I haven't tweaked the central server config before. Yes, I understand the difference. So just to confirm i got it right, I'd use the `RedirectMap` from here [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) that would control the redirections for that domain right? Do you know whether this would overwrite other redirections rules for other domains, i.e. if I have other websites on same server that have their own .htaccess files rules would they get overwritten by what's in the `RedirectMap`? thanks!

Comment: Rewrite rules won't "overwrite" each other, there is no connection between them. But the order of execution is important and may very well lead to unexpected results: rules are always executed from top to bottom in the file they are implemented in. First those rules in the central configuration, then, if enabled, those in distributed configuration files starting at the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder going up the requested path. So yes, you have to take care not to accidentally render other rules useless. Rule of thumb: exceptions first, more general rules later.

Comment: awesome thanks @arkascha !